# How to emulate keypress in selenium webdriver using phpunit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

So I have this code:

```
$this->click(PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_SessionCommand_Click::RIGHT);
```

It works  when emulating **Right Click** but how about emulating a keyboard press?
Are there any codes similar to this that doesn't require me to use `$this->webDriver` and `sendKeys`?

Comment: What action you want to perform from keyboard??

Answer (score 0):

Use this below line to perform Enter action:

```
    // pressing "Enter"
    $this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

Comment: sorry.. but it's not the answer i'm looking for

Comment: Then what is your requirement??..The code i have posted will perform Escape and Enter action in selenium automation.

Comment: I'm using phpunit.. and I'm pretty sure driver won't work in my code.. that's why i indicated in my post that I'm finding a code that doesn't require me to use sendKeys and webDriver syntax

Comment: I have edited my post. Once check it out. And let me know is it working or not.